# invalid regexp group

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have regular expression

`(?<=\s)(?:#sidebar-right-1|#BlogArchive1|#ArchiveList|#BlogArchive1_ArchiveList|#PopularPosts)(?=\s|{)`

I got syntax error invalid regex group. Where is problem?

I applied it like this:

rules[r].selectorText.match(new RegExp(ids, 'gm'))

Comment: The `{` in the end should be escaped.

Comment: Like this? `(?<=\s)(?:#sidebar-right-1|#BlogArchive1|#ArchiveList|#BlogArchive1_ArchiveList|#PopularPosts)(?=\s|\{)` same error. This is the string displayed in debugger.

Comment: The `{` is not the problem. It _could_ be escaped, but it doesn't have to. Regex engines don't treat it as a special character if it is not followed by an integer.

Comment: `(?<=\s)` is the problem, but next time show the complete code _and_ error that is generated.

Comment: There was not error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that javascript's regexs do not support positive lookbehind assertions (i.e. the `(?<=\s)` part).

Comment: Yep, the error started to appear then I added the assertions.